# AUTO_INCREMENT se salta números en los Id's en Maria DB

Tags: sql, mariadb

estoy aprendiendo la teoría de Base de Datos Relacional junto con el lenguaje SQL con el gestor de base de datos MARIA DB, por lo que para crear un ID único en una tabla uso el parámetro AUTO_INCREMENT, todo las inserciones se hacen correctamente, sin embargo, cuando alguna inserción no se realiza de manera correcta, en vez de seguir con la numeración cronológica, se salta números, ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer que las secuencias, aun fallidas o no, siempre tengan ID´s ordenados numéricamente?

Comment: Hola Luis, la pregunta debe ser autocontenida, esto es que no dependa de imágenes o enlaces, por favor, edita tu pregunta elimina la imagen, y agrega tu código y el mensaje de error como texto, gracias..

Comment: ¿Para qué? El `id` es simplemente un número único. El valor mismo no importa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagina este escenario:

- Tú haces una insert, y se te asigna un valor.
- Otro usuario realiza la misma operación solo fracciones de segundos después que tú, pero antes que la transacción tuya termine. También se le asigna un valor autoincrementable (+1 que el tuyo)
- Luego tu transacción falla y la del otro usuario no

Si analizas lo anterior te darás cuenta que se genera un lio terrible al tratar de asegurar la secuencialidad. Sin contar que tú siempre puedes borrar un dato del medio, ahí vuelve a tener el mismo problema

Vamos a ver que dice la [documentación](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/auto_increment/#missing-values)

**(Traducción)**

> **Valores que faltan**
>
> Una columna AUTO_INCREMENT normalmente tiene valores faltantes. Esto
> sucede porque si se elimina una fila o se actualiza explícitamente un
> valor AUTO_INCREMENT, los valores antiguos nunca se vuelven a
> utilizar. La instrucción REPLACE también elimina una fila y su valor
> se desperdicia. Con InnoDB, los valores pueden ser reservados por una
> transacción; **pero si la transacción falla (por ejemplo, debido a un**
> **ROLLBACK) el valor reservado se perderá.**
>
> Por lo tanto, con AUTO_INCREMENT los valores se pueden usar para ordenar los
> resultados en orden cronológico, **pero no para crear una secuencia**
> **numérica**.

Por tanto no es posible hacer lo que deseas, al menos no de la manera que lo planteas. Quizás usando `Sequences` y creando una función SQL sea posible, o a través de programación usando un lenguaje como PHP, JAVA, C#. Pero no con `auto_increment`